# Tab view not working right on UWP Windows UI Library

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am making an app for UWP on Visual Studio that uses the  Windows UI Library for the tab view component. I was following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tab-view) and it gives the following code to use:

xaml:
`<muxc:TabView AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested"/>` 
c#:

```
// Add a new Tab to the TabView
private void TabView_AddTabButtonClick(muxc.TabView sender, object args)
{
    var newTab = new muxc.TabViewItem();
    newTab.IconSource = new muxc.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };
    newTab.Header = "New Document";

    // The Content of a TabViewItem is often a frame which hosts a page.
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    newTab.Content = frame;
    frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));

    sender.TabItems.Add(newTab);
}

// Remove the requested tab from the TabView
private void TabView_TabCloseRequested(muxc.TabView sender, muxc.TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    sender.TabItems.Remove(args.Tab);
}
```

I added that code to my project and and at first glance it looks normal.
However when try to interact, there are problems. I can only create a new tab if I click at the very bottom edge of the " + " icon. I also cant exit any tabs or interact with them.
**Here's a gif of my problem:**
https://im7.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-7-565b1f0b4531.gif

Does anybody have a fix for this?
Thanks for any help

Comment: After you click at the “+” icon and a tab is created, you could click the tab and the content of Page1 is shown if Page1 has UI controls. You could exit a tab by clicking the “x” icon in the right of the tab or switch to another tab by click another tab. The gif image is broken and I can not view your problem. If your problem is not resolved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TabStripHeader and TabStripFooter.
TabStripHeader's children is Grid and set name it to `ShellTitlebarInset`,
TabStripFooter's children is Grid and set name it to `CustomDragRegion`
and set background to `Transparent` for both.

Use `CustomDragRegion` as Title Bar.

**Like Example**:-

```
<muxc:TabView>
    <muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
        <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="Transparent" />
    </muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
    <muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
        <Grid Grid.Column="3" x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="Transparent" />
    </muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
</muxc:TabView>
```

**And C# Example**:-

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(CustomDragRegion);
}

private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    if (FlowDirection == FlowDirection.LeftToRight)
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
    }
    else
    {
        CustomDragRegion.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
        ShellTitlebarInset.MinWidth = sender.SystemOverlayRightInset;
    }

    CustomDragRegion.Height = ShellTitlebarInset.Height = sender.Height;
}
```

***Note:*** To ensure that the tabs in the title bar are not occluded by shell content, you must account for left and right overlays. In LTR layouts, the right inset includes the caption buttons and the drag region. The reverse is true in RTL. The `SystemOverlayLeftInset` and `SystemOverlayRightInset` values are in terms of physical left and right, so reverse these too when in RTL.

Click [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view#display-tabview-tabs-in-a-windows-titlebar) for ***More Information***

Comment: This works great! But there is one problem, whenever I try to drag or click on a tab, a new tab row appears below the original. If you know how to fix this, that would be fantastic! Here's a working gif: [link](https://s9.gifyu.com/images/ezgif-2-5a2e0f0dbcdf.gif)

Comment: I understand that you navigate the same page on the page so It creates a row programmatically. Try to navigate different page on the page. When you drag and drop then a tab is selected.